# SHA1 and SHA-256 in Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

To use Google Firebase's feature like Social media Authentication one needs to add the SHA1 keys into the Firebase project.
In my case I have two different firebase projects - one for Production and the other for Staging. Since the two builds are signed with different keys, I now have 2 set of SHA1 and SHA256 keys.
Firebase does not allow us to use the same SHA1 keys in two different projects and it is understandable. But for the same signing , one can add the SHA1 key in one Firebase project and SHA-256 in another Firebase project.

How does that work ? Does it mean that we can have 2 projects for the same singing. And if that is the case then why do we have restriction only with SHA1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase accepts both SHA-1 and SHA-256 hashes but both of them are used for different purposes.
SHA1 is meant for OAuth2 client and API key for the app.
SHA256 is meant for Firebase dynamic link.

Since the purpose of each is different, it doesn't mind you using the SHA1 and SHA256 hash of the same certificate in two different projects.